# How can scrollTop has no effect in Javascript while scrolling is available by mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

All of

```
$(document).scrollTop(100);

$(window).scrollTop(100);

$('html body').scrollTop(100);
```

does not scroll and does nothing.

How can it be?

**UPDATE**

To reproduce the problem.

1. Open this page in Chrome: http://test.beyondmap.com/properties?view=map
2. Open Chrome developer tools.
3. Go to console.
4. Enter the following command in console

`$(window).scrollTop(100)`

5. Nothing will happen.
6. Expected: scroll down by 100 pixels.

**UPDATE 2**

I wrote the following HTML, opened it in separate window, reduced it's size so that scrollbars appear and it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<input type="button" value="scroll" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollTop+=10">

<p>My paragraph 0.</p>

<p>My paragraph 1.</p>

<p>My paragraph 2.</p>

<p>My paragraph 3.</p>

<p>My paragraph 4.</p>

<p>My paragraph 5.</p>

<p>My paragraph 6.</p>

<p>My paragraph 7.</p>

<p>My paragraph 8.</p>

<p>My paragraph 9.</p>

<p>My paragraph 10.</p>

<p>My paragraph 11.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have CSS rule `html, body { height: 100%; }`, change it to `html, body { height: auto; }` and all scroll functions come available for use.

For smooth scrolling effect you can use;

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 100}, 2000);
```

Targeting both html and body brings you great browser support.

**UPDATE**

Now after spending some time looking into this issue more closely, there are two bugs causing issues here;

"scrollTop of BODY always 0 when HTML element has overflow: hidden"
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633573

"scrollTop property breaks with body height 100% overflow auto"
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423935

Other way to fix the issue, is to remove the `overflow-x: hidden;` css rule from the html selector.

**Broken version of your simple demo**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {  
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<input type="button" value="scroll" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollTop+=10">

<p>My paragraph 0.</p>

<p>My paragraph 1.</p>

<p>My paragraph 2.</p>

<p>My paragraph 3.</p>

<p>My paragraph 4.</p>

<p>My paragraph 5.</p>

<p>My paragraph 6.</p>

<p>My paragraph 7.</p>

<p>My paragraph 8.</p>

<p>My paragraph 9.</p>

<p>My paragraph 10.</p>

<p>My paragraph 11.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I see scroll bar at right and can scroll it by mouse!

Comment: If you have height 100% on html or body they take "100% size of the view port" and JavaScript doesn't understand that there is something to scroll. If you change the height from 100% to auto, you are also able to scroll the page via JavaScript.

Comment: Can you explain why? The scroll should happen INSIDE that element. For example, I can have `DIV` with height 100px and scroll inside it: https://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/4kkt5y9f/2/  Having fixed height does not contradict ability to scroll?

Comment: 100% height and 100px are not the same thing. 100% on body or html, from JS point of view, takes 100% of the viewport, which causes issues for JavaScript scrollTop API. I do not know why it is this way, but I think JavaScript just doesn't understand there is something to scroll. Hopefully there is someone smarter than me who knows why browsers and javascript handle this case as they do. If you need to keep the height 100%, then you need to change the height to auto during the scroll and then back to 100% after scrolling is done.

Comment: See my `UPDATE 2` please.

Comment: Updated my answer, there is a bug in the webkit browsers. There are  2 ways to fix it;
1) Set height of html to `auto`
2) Remove overflow-x: hidden; rule from the html element